# Issues using perforce command line under cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, perforce

So, virtually cannot use the the perforce command line for anything other than syncing.
My workspace root is mapped to C:\
Here's a line of my client spec:
//claims1.0/main/... //cthiel/code/claims1.0/main/...

Any time I fire up cygwin and attempt to work with any files in my depot (such as p4 edit ), I get an error along the lines of:
Path '/cygdrive/c/code/commonTest/main.p4ignore' is not under client's root 'C:\'.

The paths aren't matching up, because the equivalent of C:\ for cygwyn is /cygdrive/c. So it's never able to find files with the perforce command line.

Is there a way to fix this? It's highly annoying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even mo' betta':
Use the cygwin p4 client:
http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r07.2/bin.cygwinx86/p4.exe

Just make sure this is in your path before the Perforce/p4.exe. Et voila.

Comment: this version this link points to is obviously not the latest/greatest, but the other versions are also available in sibling directories.

Comment: You can get the latest client from here: http://www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list

Click on "Other" and then "cygwin"

Comment: the latest cygwin perforce client worked for me, thanks Phillip!  I was having trouble with P4CONFIG being "ignored" under cygwin when using the NTX86 2008 client.   The problem doesn't occur with the 2010 and 2011 NTX86 p4.exe clients.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I know I'm invoking the correct p4 but it simply does nothing, prints nothing... For now I'm sticking with the previous solution.

Comment: Perforce's web site reports that their [Cygwin-native client was discontinued May 2013](http://perforce.com/downloads/complete_list/archived/archived_perforce_platform?qt-others=1#qt-others).

Answer (score 35):

Found a solution:
Add this to your .bashrc:

```
function p4() {
export PWD=`cygpath -wa .`
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4.exe $@
}
```

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: I found this preferable to the cygwin p4 client for some reason.  Probably my own lack of knowledge - I found that the cygwin binary required me to set a password via environment variable (always yucky to see env variables with sensitive data), and even still I got the same error.  This worked magically.

Comment: You are a life-saver. PWD was the issue in my script, because I had mapped my %TEMP% as /tmp :-)

Comment: I found that *not* exporting PWD is better because changing $PWD can mess up emacs and also changes bash prompt to windows format. I prefer doing this: function p4() {PWD=`cygpath -ma .` "`which p4`" $@}. This way PWD is only changed inside the p4 command.

Comment: To extend the fix to scripts/subshells, add this after the alias: `export -f p4` Background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471364/how-do-i-list-the-functions-defined-in-my-shell https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427946/bash-script-is-not-inheriting-its-parents-env

Answer (score 5):

You can setup altroots in your client spec, that might cover this?

Although the cygwin p4 is the solution I'd go for. But I would go for the latest version: http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r09.2/bin.cygwinx86/p4.exe - it'll work with any older server, but will have fewer bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Please note, the [Perforce CLI client for CygWin has been deprecated](http://perforce.com/perforce/downloads/archived_drupal.html#cygwinx86) and will be no longer supported after 5/1/2013, according to the Perforce web site. There is discussion of this topic at the Perforce support forums, including [a poll which attempts to gauge the level of interest](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1551-cygwin-client-support/) in continuing support for the CygWin client. Support is being discontinued for financial reasons (license fees to Redhat for commercial Cygwin distribution); so if sufficient interest is shown, that decision *may* be reconsidered.

If you use the P4 Cygwin client, ever have, or have any interest in the subject, I urge you to participate in the poll. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of the .bashrc function to avoid the cygpath overhead and finding p4.exe executable in the PATH automatically:

```
function p4() {
    PWD= `which p4` "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alt root seems to work fine for me. However I am not using cygwin. My source code resides in linux server and I have client in windows machine. I have mapped server's workspace on windows using network drive.