# How do I list the functions defined in my shell?

Tags: bash, shell, function, unix

I can type alias to show a list of all the aliases.

But for functions, all I can do is grep my `.bash_profile`.

That only gets the ones in that file, not those defined in subsidiary files or dynamically.

Is there a more convenient way to find out what functions are currently defined?

Comment: @AlastairIrvine Thanks for the duplicate nomination; however, I resolved it the other way around. This question has significantly more views and upvotes, as well as a broader selection of answers; and the accepted answer on your nominated duplicate is decidedly obscure and arguably just wrong.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

`declare -F`

> Function names and definitions may be listed with the `-f` option to the
>   `declare` builtin command (see Bash Builtins). The `-F` option to `declare`
>   will list the function names only
>   (and optionally the source file and line number).

[Bash Reference Manual](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref)

Comment: in GNU bash  4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
-F lists names / -f lists whole function

Comment: To get the "optional" source file/line#, it appears you must enable extdebug (`shopt -s extdebug`) AND supply one or more function names to the `declare -F` command. IOW, `declare -F` does **not** supply filenames/line#s even when extdebug is enabled, which is not clear from the documentation, nor is it particularly intuitive, IMO.

Comment: See @user495470's answer below for a better solution.

Comment: In `zsh` (Mac) this was helpful: `$ declare -f > functions.sh`

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac. Prints `EPOCHREALTIME`. `compgen -A function` from @DavidT and @Lri answers works

Answer (score 105):

Assuming bash shell:

```
typeset -f
```

will list the functions.

```
typeset -F
```

will list just the function names.

Comment: My bash v4.1.17(9)-release says: `Obsolete.  See \`help declare'.`

Comment: It's still nice to know it's a synonym.

Answer (score 84):

```
declare -F
```

will give you the names of all functions

```
type function_name
```

will give you the source for a particular function

Comment: Or just use declare -f   (lowercase) for the source

Comment: +1 for `type` as this also works for aliases (without you needing to know whether your command is one or the other).

Answer (score 78):

`declare -F` actually prints declare commands and not only function names:

```
$ declare -F
declare -f function1
declare -f function2
```

You can use `compgen -A function` to print only function names:

```
$ compgen -A function
function1
function2
```

Comment: `compgen -A function` was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice! I wanted aliases as well in my case ... you can get both aliases and functions with `compgen -a -A function`

Comment: +1 and I've used the following to output my personal functions only (on Linux Debian): `compgen -A function | grep "^[a-z]\+" | grep -vE "^dequote|^quote|^in_array"`

Comment: Apparently not available in MacOS / BSD.

Answer (score 38):

**typeset** is obsolete, please use:

```
declare -f
```

or

```
declare -f function_name
```

or

```
type function_name
```

Answer (score 8):

```
set | grep " ()"
```

In place of *grep* you can also use *fgrep* or *hgrep* 
(hgrep is my personal favorite, it's grep but it hi-lites the 'grep-ped' result.

***hgrep*** can be found here: [ACME Labs hgrep](http://www.acme.com/software/hgrep/)

Comment: This will list functions but also variables that have ` ()` in value

Comment: @AloisMahdal Here's one that works: `set | grep " () $" | cut -d' ' -f1`. But it's overly complicated compared to the other answers.

Comment: `grep` is not a good solution for this, strings that match function definitions will cause false positives. @wjandrea can still be caught by multi line strings, as will any regex.

Answer (score 8):

I'm no expert at this, still learning, but after finding this question and its answer because I wanted the same, I wrote the following (based on "[The Archetypal Paul's declare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471405/4516124)" answer) to give me ultimately what I was after: a formatted list of both aliases and functions:

```sh
function functionaliaslist() {
    echo
    echo -e "\033[1;4;32m""Functions:""\033[0;34m"
    declare -F | awk {'print $3'}
    echo
    echo -e "\033[1;4;32m""Aliases:""\033[0;34m"
    alias | awk {'print $2'} | awk -F= {'print $1'}
    echo
    echo -e "\033[0m"
}
```

That was before I saw [Lri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278090/4516124), and so extrapolating from that, I replace the `declare` and `alias` lines with appropriate `compgen` commands instead, to get:

```sh
function functionaliaslist() {
    echo
    echo -e "\033[1;4;32m""Functions:""\033[0;34m"
    compgen -A function
    echo
    echo -e "\033[1;4;32m""Aliases:""\033[0;34m"
    compgen -A alias
    echo
    echo -e "\033[0m"
}
```

Woks a treat for what I wanted. Sharing in case it helps anyone else.

There are a multitude of other "actions" available to `compgen -A [action]` (and other options for `compgen` of course).  I found a good write-up [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151120) which also includes a link to the man page (because `man compgen` doesn't work in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

## Bash shell script specific answer

(because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630812/get-a-list-of-function-names-in-a-shell-script) was marked as a duplicate of this one)

If you have functions exported in your shell a called script will see them. But luckily, they get marked as such.

### Copy-Pasta Demo script

```
#!/bin/bash
foo(){ :;}; bar(){ :;}; baz(){ :;}; export -f foo bar

export -pf

bash -c $'spam(){ :;}; \
echo "RAW:"; \
declare -pF; \
echo "FILTERED:"; \
declare -pF | awk \'$2 !~ /x/{print$3}\''
```

### Transcript in Bash

```
/tmp $ foo(){ :;}; bar(){ :;}; baz(){ :;}; export -f foo bar

/tmp $ export -pf
bar ()
{
    :
}
declare -fx bar
foo ()
{
    :
}
declare -fx foo

/tmp $ bash -c $'spam(){ :;}; echo "RAW:"; declare -pF; echo "FILTERED:"; declare -pF | awk \'$2 !~ /x/{print$3}\''
RAW:
declare -fx bar
declare -fx foo
declare -f spam
FILTERED:
spam
```